# How to properly define the home (/) route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Let's say I am defining the following route in Laravel 5.3:

```
Route::resource('bands', 'BandController');
```

The default route example coming when you start a new Laravel project has the following:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

How do I make `bands` route to be the default one when no controller is called instead of `welcome`? Meaning `/`?

I did read docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) but didn't found anything. Any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place that block inside `laravel/app/routes.php` instead of a Controller (4.x)

Place that block inside `laravel/app/Http/routes.php` instead of a Controller (5.1)

Place that block inside `laravel/app/routes/web.php` instead of a Controller (5.3)

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return view('welcome');
});
```

You can redirect default to anywhere you want, i.e.:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to( '/bands');
    // OR: return Redirect::intended('/bands'); // if using authentication
});
```

Comment: Take a look again, apologies I didn't explain my answer so good, this is not what I want is the opposite, I want `bands` to be the default route

Comment: This is not the proper route directory for 5.x

Answer (score 3):

As @Patrick mentioned, you can simply redirect to the `/bands` route.  However,  I have to warn you that the redirect will actually change the URL in the navigation pane of the web browser. I would have suggested that you just ask the home route to use the `index` method of your `BandController` as follows:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses'=>'BandController@index']);
```